# Why can't the utility function be condensed to a single argument in Apollo?

Tags: r

I am using Apollo for an ordered logit model. Since I have to make over 100 specifications, I wanted to condense it a bit, so I don't have to make it too hard and painful for myself to go through the process.

If I condense betas by first specifying them as a single argument like this:

```
randstad <- c(
  #b_randstad_is = 0,
  b_randstad_not = 0,
  b_randstad_to = 0,
  b_randstad_from = 0
)

wdist <- c(
  b_weekdist_dec    = 0,
  b_weekdist_inc    = 0,
  b_weekdist_same         = 0,
  #b_weekdist_nojob              = 0,
  b_weekdist_lostjob             = 0,
  b_weekdist_gotjob              = 0,
  b_weekdist_alwayswfh  = 0,
  b_weekdist_wfhtocommuting = 0,
  b_weekdist_commutingtowfh = 0,
  b_weekdist_differingaddresses  = 0
)

spec1 <- c(
  randstad,
  wdist
)

apollo_beta = c(spec1,
                tau_nautos_change_1                = 0,
                tau_nautos_change_2                = 1)
```

It totally works, and it's very handy cause I can save a lot of coding space by doing that and condense all the specifications in a separate file.

However, doing the same with the utility function does not work. Since it is an equation and not a list, I use the `quote` function:

```
uspec1 <- quote(
  #b_randstad_is*randstad_change_randstad + 
  b_randstad_not*randstad_change_notrandstad + 
  b_randstad_to*randstad_change_torandstad + 
  b_randstad_from*randstad_change_fromrandstad +
  b_weekdist_dec*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_decreasedcommute +
  b_weekdist_inc*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_increasedcommute +
  b_weekdist_same*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_samecommute +
  #b_weekdist_nojob*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_nojob +
  b_weekdist_lostjob*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_lostjob +
  b_weekdist_gotjob*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_gotjob +
  b_weekdist_alwayswfh*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_alwaysworkfromhome +
  b_weekdist_wfhtocommuting*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_workfromhometocommuting +
  b_weekdist_commutingtowfh*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_commutingtoworkfromhome +
  b_weekdist_differingaddresses*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_differingaddresses
) 

... 

  ol_settings = list(outcomeOrdered = nautos_change,
                     utility        =   
                                      uspec1,
                     tau            = list(tau_nautos_change_1, tau_nautos_change_2))
```

This gives the error `"Error in apollo_preprocess(inputs = ol_settings, modelType, functionality, :  "utility" for model component "OL" needs to be a function, a scalar, or a vector/matrix/cube with one row per observation in the "database""`

Keep in mind that if I simply write:

```
  ol_settings = list(outcomeOrdered = nautos_change,
                     utility        =   
  #b_randstad_is*randstad_change_randstad + 
  b_randstad_not*randstad_change_notrandstad + 
  b_randstad_to*randstad_change_torandstad + 
  b_randstad_from*randstad_change_fromrandstad +
  b_weekdist_dec*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_decreasedcommute +
  b_weekdist_inc*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_increasedcommute +
  b_weekdist_same*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_samecommute +
  #b_weekdist_nojob*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_nojob +
  b_weekdist_lostjob*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_lostjob +
  b_weekdist_gotjob*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_gotjob +
  b_weekdist_alwayswfh*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_alwaysworkfromhome +
  b_weekdist_wfhtocommuting*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_workfromhometocommuting +
  b_weekdist_commutingtowfh*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_commutingtoworkfromhome +
  b_weekdist_differingaddresses*weekdist_woonwerk_changecat_differingaddresses,
                     tau            = list(tau_nautos_change_1, tau_nautos_change_2))
```

It does work.

Also, if I call `uspec1`, I get the exact thing I want to put in there.

Why does it not work to condense it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with apollo specifically. This seems to just be an issue about how R itself evaluates function calls. Note that a quoted expression is not the same as a plain expression. Consider the case of

```
foo <- function(a, b) {
  a+b
}

x <- 5
foo(x, 2)
# [1] 10

q <- quote(x)
foo(q, 4)
# Error in a + b : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

You can't just swap in a quoted expression anywhere a regular expression appears. You need to unquote the expression. One way to do that is with `do.call()` to build the call you want to evaulate. In this case it would look like

```
do.call("foo", list(q, 2))
# [1] 7
```

Basically you create a call to `foo` and build the list of parameters which would include the quoted symbol name. In your call to list, it might look something like

```
ol_settings = do.call("list", list(
   outcomeOrdered = quote(nautos_change),
   utility        = uspec1,
   tau            = quote(list(tau_nautos_change_1, tau_nautos_change_2))
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for coming with a solution despite me not having a reproducable example. Why is it not possible to just put the `do.call` around uspec1?

Comment: Because `do.call` works for building and evaluating function calls. It does not operate on generic expressions. Function like `substitute` can work on generic expressions but it doesn't do the evaluation.

Comment: Can I do something different than `quote` that would achieve the same result?

Comment: Any chance you might know what could cause the error "Error in apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities,  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" when I run the Apollo code after using this method?